# function overloading in c++ and passing by reference

Tags: c++

can someone please explain to me why a foo("Hello, I am an referncing string."); in a main() would call void foo(const string& s) and not the other defined foo() functions?

```
void foo(string& s)
{
    cout << "(foo1): " << s << endl;
    s = "Greetings from 'foo1'.";
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void foo(string* s)
{
    cout << "(foo2): " << *s << endl;
    *s = "Greetings from 'foo2'.";
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void foo(const string& s)
{
    cout << "(foo3): " << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: because it is the best match. `"Hello, I am an referncing string.` is a string literal (a constant string).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the missing code you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` has a *non-explicit* constructor to a `const char*`.

Your *anonymous temporary* string literal (which has a type `const char[N]` where `N` is the number of characters in the string, including the implicit NUL at the end) can *decay* to a `const char*` when passed as a function argument.

And an *anonymous temporary* is allowed to *bind* to a `const` reference.

Therefore with the three overloads you have, the one containing `foo3` is viable and therefore selected at compilation time.

(The function containing `foo1` is not viable since an anonymous temporary cannot bind to a non-`const` reference - despite some earlier compilers allowing it in error. `foo2` is far from being acceptable as that requires a pointer to a `std::string` to be passed).

Do research the *italicised* terms here - there's quite a lot going on here.

Comment: Followup question: if we introduce a 4th overload `void foo(char *s)
{
  cout << "(foo4): ";
}` why is this a better match than `foo(const string& s)`?

Comment: @Bathsheba. Infinite thanks. I would do my research  right away. I am new to C++ and still have a lot of things to learn

Comment: @MichaelWalz it isn't;  There's no conversion from `const char*` to `char *`

Comment: @MichaelWalz It isn't (not since and including C++03 anyway) although many compilers allow it (blame C for that), but will fail if you crank up the pedantry level.

Comment: @UKMonkey apparentyl there _is_ a conversion: [Live demo](https://www.ideone.com/o9MO9D).

Comment: @MichaelWalz sorry, can't see that link for my proxy.  :(

Comment: @UKMonkey see Batshsheba's comment. If you compile with `--pedantic` there _is_ a warning `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   foo("Hello");`, so you are right.

Comment: @MichaelWalz 10001 reasons to compile with `-Wall -Werror`

Answer (score 0):

Because it's the best overload. The type of `"Hello, I am an referncing string."` is `char*` (more or less) and `std::string` has a constructor from `const char*`. So the compiler creates a *temporary* `std::string` and calls foo3. It doesn't call foo2 because there's no way to create a pointer to a `std::string` and it doesn't call foo1 because of the rule that you cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary.